# Adding a background image to a Dashboard using dash/plotly wipes out content

Tags: html, css, plotly-dash

I'm trying to add a background image to my Dash/Plotly dashboard.  I have done this by modifying the css using the following:

```
body {
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("/assets/rink.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  position: fixed;}
```

This displays the image - it looks great - but it wipes out everything else on the dashboard.  How do I push the image to the background (I want to send it to the back)?

Thanks

Comment: Tough to say without seeing the HTML, but maybe look into [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). It's possible that adding `z-index: -1` would work if it is indeed a stacking issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had referred to the css in the html.Div([],style='body').  I removed the style='body' and now it's truely in the background and looks great!